# Would a Java HashSet<String>'s contains() method test equality of the strings or object identity?

Tags: java, string, reference, hashset

Let's say I have this code in Java:

```
HashSet<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>();
String a = "hello";
String b = "hello";
wordSet.add(a);
```

Would `wordSet.contains(b);` return `true` or `false`? From what I understand, `a` and `b` refer to different objects even though their values are the same. So `contains()` should return `false`. However, when I run this code, it returns `true`. **Will it always return `true` no matter where String object `b` is coming from as long as `b` contains the value `"hello"`? Am I guaranteed this always?** If not, when am I not guaranteed this? And what if I wanted to do something similar with objects other than Strings?

Comment: In your example, a and b actually point to the same object instance. Which may be misleading in tests. Use new String(...) to force different objects. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It uses `equals()` to compare the data. Below is from the [javadoc for Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29)

> adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no
>   element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)).

The `equals()` method for String does a character by character comparison. From the [javadoc for String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object

Answer (score 8):

Actually, HashSet does **neither**.

Its implementation uses a HashMap, and here's the relevant code that determines if the set `contains()` (actually it's inside HashMap's getEntry() method):

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
```

which:

- requires the hashes to equal, and
- requires *either* object equality or `equals()` returns true

The answer is "yes": `wordSet.contains(b)` will always return `true`

Comment: The OP asked about `HashSet<String>`.  The `String` class's `hashCode` method returns equal values for two strings for which `equals` is true.  The `String` class's `equals` method returns true if its argument is the same object as the object for which it's called.  So the condition that you've quoted is logically equivalent to `equals()`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, both a and b refer to the same object, because string literals in Java are automatically interned.

Comment: ... which is why he/she said  'Will it always return true no matter where String object b is coming from as long as b contains the value "hello"?'

Comment: `From what I understand, a and b refer to different objects even though their values are the same` - Im pretty sure thats not what he thought.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right.  In any case, the question that he/she asked was whether HashSets use equality or identity; it's just his/her example that's a tad flawed.

Comment: Then why is there an intern() method if they are automatically interned?

Comment: Because they're only automatically interned if they start out as literals.  But if you get the String from somewhere else (like you read it from a file, or build it up from substrings, for example), then interning it will change its identity.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. A set would be pretty useless unless it called the equals() method to determine equality. wordset.contains(b) will return true because a.equals(b) == true.
2. You cannot be totally sure that a and b are pointing to different objects. Checkout String.intern() for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately `contains` will check for `equals` method rather then its object id validation for contains method. Hence `equals` method will be called for `contains` call.
This is the call structure of `contains` method.

```
private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return map.containsKey(o);
    }


    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return getEntry(key) != null;
    }


    final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
        int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
        for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
             e != null;
             e = e.next) {
            Object k;
            if (e.hash == hash &&
                ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                return e;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: And this is same for HashSet?

Comment: Yes, for `HashSet` also the `equals` method will be called for `contains`

Answer (score 0):

Equality.  In your example, `contains()` returns true, because the HashSet checks `a.equals( b )`.